# Let's encrypt on Ubuntu Snappy

Tags: apache2, encryption, ubuntu-core

Just got my first Ubuntu Snappy running on a Raspberry Pi 2 and would very much like to enjoy Let's encrypt on it. I got it working on my other web server, but feel that this might not apply on Snappy Core, right?

For example, Let's Encrypt provides a Python script for install of the certificates, but on Snappy the same files does not apply as normal about Apache2 and stuff, right?

Where to start.

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Right-- snaps need to include all of their dependencies, so for instance the ownCloud snap bundles its own Apache, its own MySQL, etc. This is doable, but it's something you'd have to support in the snap that bundles the web server.

Comment: So it's either build your own ownCloud snap package with Let's Encrypt bundled, or feature request in the existing ownCloud snap package?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can totally do this all from the command-line (manually rather that using LE's Apache plugin), but the snap you're using needs to have an Apache that e.g. has SSL enabled.

Comment: Aha, well I am using the owncloud-snap package (that you seem to be a part of, correct?) on the ownCloud Pi drive. I have not yet found anything about whether or not that Apache has SSL enabled, but I found that there's been some discussion about user cert and LE.

Comment: Yeah I recognized your name, which is why I mentioned the ownCloud snap as an example :) . However, owncloud-specific discussions should probably take place over there-- specifically I recommend [this issue](https://github.com/kyrofa/owncloud-snap/issues/44) as it'll fill you in on where we stand regarding LE (and SSL/TLS in general).